# Probability of picking exactly one correct from a pool of 6 incorrect and 4 correct

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So as the question says. You have 6 incorrect objects and 4 correct ones. What are the odds that, when picking 3 of them at random, you end up with exactly one of them being correct.

This seems to be quite trivial but I'm having issues since my solution differs from the provided one. Also, I've written a program that simulates it and it seems to be leaning towards my solution.

Anyways, the way I did it is just by multiplying $\dfrac{4}{10}\dfrac{6}{9}\dfrac{5}{8}$ with the result being $\dfrac{1}{6}$. The reasoning is that you first have a 4 in 10 chance of picking the correct one and then you need to pick the incorrect one 2 times with 6 in 9 and 5 in 8 chances. I thought that maybe the fact that the order doesn't matter is making my calculation off but since you can write the product as a big fraction and commute everything, that can't be the problem.

The provided solution is $\dfrac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}}$. I can see how that would work as well so I can't really say what the problem might be with their solution.

Anyways, I wrote a program that picks 3 numbers out of [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1] at random. It does it 100000 times and the number of times it got exactly one 1 is around 18800. That's obviously much closer to my $\dfrac{1}{6}$ than their $\dfrac{1}{2}$. Is their solution wrong? If so, why?

Edit:
Now that I think about it, my solution should be the incorrect one since it answers the question of what the odds are that I FIRST pick a correct one and then 2 incorrect ones, but why would the simulation lean towards my solution then?

Comment: You calculate the probability that you *first* pick a correct one and then two wrong ones. There are $3$ possible orders here: CWW, WCW and WWC. Note that $3\times\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I've noticed that (see my edit) but it still doesn't explain the simulation.

Comment: Your first proposed solution is not right, though it can be made right by multiplying by $3$, the number of orders in which you can get $1$ correct, $2$ incorrect. As to the simulation, presumably the simulation follows the wrong analysis, the program counts the cases where you get good, then bad, then bad.

Comment: @drhab Yeah but the order does not matter here:
WWC yields $6/10\times 5/9\times 4/8$. No matter the order you still have decreasing denomitators $10\to 9 \to 8$ and the same goes for the numerator $6\to5$ and another one that is 4. The only thing you forgot is to count the number of such sequences, i.e. 3.

Comment: Yes, three identical numbers, which you then should add.

Comment: In any case, this is the code for the simulation if anyone wants to try and find the error. https://gist.github.com/7550678

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I remove the shuffle, it starts leaning toward 1/2. I'll leave it to someone smarter than me to find out why. In any case, consider the question answered.

Comment: Your code for shuffle is wrong. "arr.Add(array[rand.Next(i, array.Count - 1)]);" picks up a random element in an array containing 6 zeros and 4 ones. You might end up creating a new list that is shuffled but not having exactly 4 1's and 6 0's.

Comment: You're absolutely right. At first I was using arrays and I had working code but when switching to lists I must have changed swapped the variable name for the parameter name.

Comment: Also aside, the shuffle should not matter because every look at the list is random; it doesn't matter where the 1's or 0's are located. [code](https://gist.github.com/sudarsanvsr/7551366).

Answer (score 2):

I just tried running the simulation and it works (out of $100000$, I got the number of trials in which only 1 correct object picked up as $49982$, fairly converging to $\frac{1}{2}$).

**Code: (Octave)**

> sum = 0;
>  res = 0;
>  a=[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1];
>  for i =
>   1:100000;
>  [junk,index] = sort(rand(1,10));
>  pick =
>   index(1);
>  sum = sum+a(pick);
>  b=[];
>  tempcount = 1;
>  for
>   j = 1:length(a);
>  if(j == pick)
>  continue
>  else
>   b(tempcount) = a(j);
>  end
>  tempcount = tempcount + 1;
>   end
>  [junk,index] = sort(rand(1,9));
>  pick = index(1);
>  sum =
>   sum+b(pick);
>  c = [];
>  tempcount = 1;
>  for j =
>   1:length(b);
>  if(j == pick)
>  continue
>  else
>  c(tempcount)
>   = b(j);
>  end
>  tempcount = tempcount + 1;
>  end
>  [junk,index] = sort(rand(1,8));
>  pick = index(1);
>  sum =
>   sum+c(pick);
>  if(sum == 1);
>  res = res + 1;
>  end
>  sum =
>   0;
>  end